# Is There a Coda 2 Plugin that does change highlighting for git / svn like netbeans has

Tags: plugins, coda, subversion, git

In netbeans, it highlights changed lines of code in green, blue or red and lets you revert changes per line. Is there a plugin that enables this kind of feature in Coda 2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Plain and simple: no.

The only way to see changes in code at the moment is to use an external diff tool, like FileMerge.app or Kaleidoscope.app.